# Why is my decision tree not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

I am a beginner to coding, especially in HTML.

I have used the basic layout of this code that I found online (I can't seem to remember where), but I wanted a similar structure to this, and wanted to populate it with my own data.

I tried to put all the code from separate files, .js and .css part into the .html code. (I searched online how to do this, also I wasn't sure about jQuery, and found on https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp that I can add it into the `<head>` section instead of downloading the library? The code below doesn't use the jQuery, but I have no clue how to use it. Can this be inserted at the top of the .html file within the `<script>` tag?

Please can anyone tell me why this only shows up on my browser as three bullet points only, and when I hover over it, the mouse changes from arrow to pointer, but doesn't click/expand.

Any help will be much appreciated!

```js
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
  tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentElement;
    var classList = parent.classList;
    if (classList.contains("open")) {
      classList.remove('open');
      var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
      for (var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++) {
        opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
      }
    } else {
      classList.add('open');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open>ul {
  display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  font-size: .8em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li>a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open>a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
  <li><a href="#">Part 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:scope` pseudo element isn't widely supported according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope but I'm not sure it was needed to acheive your goal. In fact, chrome and firefox worked fine for me and I just saw some javascript errors in IE and Edge - didn't test Safari.

This code is working for me in all of the tested browsers without javascript errors after simple removing `:scope` from the open sub element selector in the javascript.

```js
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
  tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentElement;
    var classList = parent.classList;
    if (classList.contains("open")) {
      classList.remove('open');
      var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll('.open');
      for (var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++) {
        opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
      }
    } else {
      classList.add('open');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open>ul {
  display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  font-size: .8em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li>a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open>a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
  <li><a href="#">Part 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i have tried removing the :scope, and still get the same result. The mouse changes from arrow to click, but doesn't let me click on anything.

Comment: Both your question snippet and this answer snippet are working for me in Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: im using chrome. i cant seem to click on anything.